# Finding points which divides a right trapezoid's area into equal pieces

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have a right trapezoid as follows;

[image]

We have $h$, $b$ and $a$. For any $n$, I need to divide total area of trapezoid into equal parts. I have to find a general formulation for the length of $p$ points for my study. Although I try to figure out from starting from $n=2$, $n=3$,... I couldn't able to generalize the formulation. Is there any general formulation for this?

Comment: thanks for editing, I couldn't able to put images with my current reputation :)

Comment: Do you mean that you have a solution for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and just need to generalize it to arbitrary $n$? If so, please show your existing work.

Answer (score 1):

it does not seems ok as follows:-
1) if area of triangles be equal i.e x=x', similarly if areas of trapezoidal sections be equal i.e y=y', that means x+y=x'+y' i.e area of rectangles be equal which is not true as ht is same for all rectangles and width varies.

2) x2^2=2 x1^2

x3^2=3 x1^2

x4^2=4 x1^2 as x4^2=x3^2+x1^2

Comment: as x1^2=x2^2-x1^2=x3^2-x2^2=x4^2-x3^2=H^2-x4^2= area/5 in case of division in five equal segments of the triangle. but same thing doesnt applies directly to the trapezoidal shape.